# AVAssetWriter fails with AVAssetWriterStatusFailed when reused

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I am trying to use the AVAssetWriter to encode video. I am using ARC. What I am trying to do is stream video over a socket.

**Now here is the problem**. The setup I have works the first time around. **I am unable to use the AVAssetWriter again, without restarting my application first**. If I don't restart my application, when I call [m_writer startWriting] I receive the following error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x14d06fe0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12983 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12983)}
```

- I made sure that file was deleted when the cleaup method was called.
  I used iExplorer to navigate to the temp folder where the file was
  being created. I also made sure that the status of the AVAssetWriter
  after calling finshWriting is AVAssetWriterStatusFinished.

**Edit: The error persists even If I used a different file name.**

I create an instance of the VideoEncoder class ( code below) and then I feed it raw images. Then I wait for something to be written to the output file by the AVAssetWriter using  a dispatch_source_set_event_handler(), i.e.:

```
m_inputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: m_writer.path];
m_readSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, [m_inputFile fileDescriptor], 0, m_readQueue);
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(m_readSource, ^{
  // Read bytes from file and send over socket
}
dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(m_readSource, ^{
  [self cleanup];
}
dispatch_resume(m_readSource);
```

I have created a wrapper for the AVAssetWriter called VideoEncoder. Here is how I initialize the AVAssetWriter:

```
@implementation VideoEncoder : NSObject
{
  AVAssetWriter* m_writer;
  AVAssetWriterInput* m_writerInput;
  AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor* m_pixelBufferAdaptor;
}
-(id) initWithPath:(NSString*)path  width:(int)width height:(int)height parameters:(NSDictionary*) parameters
{
  if (self = [super init])
  {
    self.path = path;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:self.path error:nil];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: self.path];

    m_writer = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:url fileType:AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie error: nil];

    NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:height], AVVideoHeightKey,
                          parameters,                      AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey,
                          nil];
    m_writerInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:settings];
    m_writerInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;

    [m_writer addInput:m_writerInput];

    NSDictionary* pixelBufferOptions = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: width*4],                   kCVPixelBufferBytesPerRowAllignmentKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt; width],                     kCVPixelBufferWidthKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt; height],                     kCVPixelBufferHeightKey,
                                        nil];

    m_pixelBufferAdaptor = [[AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor alloc]
                            initWithAssetWriterInput: m_writerInput
                            sourcePixelBufferAttributes: pixelBufferOptions];

    [m_writer startWriting];
    [m_writer startSessionAtSourceTime: kCMTimeZero];
  }
}
```

This is how I feed it raw images:

```
-(BOOL) encodeFrame:(CVPixelBufferRead)pixelBuffer time(CMTime)time;
{
  if (m_writer.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed)
  {
    return NO;
  }
  if (m_writerInput.readyForMoreMediaData == YES)
  {
    if ([m_pixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:time])
    {
      return YES:
    }
  }
  return NO;
}
```

This is how the pixel buffers are generated:

```
-(bool) encodeImage:(const char*) frameBuffer width:(int)width height:(int)height
{
  CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = NULL;
  CVReturn ret;

  ret = CVPixelBufferCraeteWithBytes( 
           kCFAllocatorDefault, 
           with, 
           height,
           kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
           (void*) frameBuffer,
           width * 4,
           NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pixelBuffer);
  if (ret == kCVReturnSuccess && pixelBuffer)
  {
    CFTimeInterval currTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    if (m_frameIndex > 0 )
    {
      int ticks = (int)((currTime - m_prevTime) * 1000) / 30;
      CMTime addTime;

      ticks = ticks <= 0 ? 1 : ticks;
      addTime = CMTimeMake(ticks, 30);
      m_timestamp = CMTimeAdd(m_timestamp, addTime);
    }
    m_prevTime = currTime;
    [m_impl encodeFrame: pixelBuffer time: m_timestamp];

    CVBufferRelease(pixelBuffer);
    m_frameIndex ++;
  }
}
```

This is how I terminate the AVAssetWriter:

```
-(void) finishWritingWithCompletionHandler(void (^)(void))handler
{
  [m_writerInput markAsFinished];
  [m_writer finishWithCompletionHandler: ^{
    handler();
  }
}
```

And here is how I use the wrapper. I use this wrapper form a C++ class. Instantiation:

```
-(void) makeFilename
{
  NSString* filename = [NSString* stringWithFormat: @"temp%d.tmp", 1];
  NSString* path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: filename];
  return path;
}

bool CFrameEncoder::StartEncoding()
{
  m_impl = CFRetain((__bridge*void)[[VideoEncoder alloc] initWithPath:[self makeFilepath] width:800 height:480 parameters: params]);
}
```

Dealloc:

```
bool CFrameEncoder::StopDecoding()
{
  [(__bridge VideoEncoder*) m_impl terminate];
  CFRelease(m_impl);
}
```

The terminate function (of the VideoEncoder class):

```
-(void) terminate
{
  if (m_readSource)
  {
    dispatch_source_cancel(m_readSource);
  }
}
// The dispatch source cancel handler
-(void) cleanup
{
  m_readQueue = nil;
  m_readSource = nil;

  [m_inputFile closeFile];

  NSString* path = m_writer.path;
  dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

  [m_writer finishWithCompletionHandler:^{
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
  }];

  dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  m_writer = nil;
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: path error: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The AVAssetWriter class can have only a limited number of instances. If your application goes over this limit, then the AVAssetWriter begins to fail with AVAssetWriterStatusFailed when you try to startWriting.

This means that there is something in my code that is preventing the AVAssetWriter from being deallocated. Does anybody know where?